# timeout freezes airodump-ng process

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian, aircrack-ng

I want to run this bash script to run airodump for a set amount of seconds before termination. after which the output goes to testreport.txt

```
#run aircrack for 5 seconds, output to file
sudo airmon-ng check kill
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo timeout 5 airodump-ng wlan0mon >> testreport.txt
```

but whenever it reaches timeout the process seems to freeze.

if I attempt to use timeout in a simple ping command like sudo timeout 5 ping  it completely functions as expected. however as soon as I introduce airodump-ng to the equation it seems to freeze the process and I have to manually pull the plug on my raspberry pi (rpi0w raspbian buster patched with re4son kernel)

does anyone know why this is, and how to fix this? I figured it might have something to do with the way timeout kills processes but nothing promising so far

I tried reading up on timeout in general, testing it in different conditions, not writing to file, running it on a different raspberry, and trying to run the command without the use of timeout (which functioned fine). for a second I thought it might be the missing 's' for seconds, but trying this gave the same result.